# ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to manually grid search for eps and min_samples, but I keep on getting an error "ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)". I am not sure what value is having issues and why.

Here is my code:

```
result = []

epses = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

min_samples = [10, 20, 30]

for v in epses:
    for n in min_samples:
        model = DBSCAN(eps = v, min_samples = n)  
        y_pred_temp = model.fit_predict(X)
        n_clusters = np.unique(model.labels_).size
        score = metrics.silhouette_score(X, y_pred_temp,metric = 'euclidean')
        result.append((v, n, score, n_clusters))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-68-598d3e8f0626>", line 7, in <module>
score = metrics.silhouette_score(X, y_pred_temp,metric = 'euclidean')

File "C:\Users\Sofia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
return f(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Sofia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 117, in silhouette_score
return np.mean(silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric=metric, **kwds))

File "C:\Users\Sofia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
return f(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Sofia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 229, in silhouette_samples
check_number_of_labels(len(le.classes_), n_samples)

File "C:\Users\Sofia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 34, in check_number_of_labels
raise ValueError("Number of labels is %d. Valid values are 2 "

ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)
```

Comment: You don't have a stack trace that goes with that error message?

Comment: Are you referring to this part? File "\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 34, in check_number_of_labels
    raise ValueError("Number of labels is %d. Valid values are 2 "

Comment: Yes, but is that all there is to it?  There should be more lines to it, including one that would tell you which line in your program produced the error.  You should put this information, whatever it is, in your question rather than in comments.  nAlso, we prefer that you not post pictures of code.  It's better if you can put a text version of your code into the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Cool.  That's much better.  That says a lot about the error.  Thanks so much for taking the time to properly format your quesiton ...and it sounds like you have an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The silhouette score is not defined when all points are in the same cluster. Either use a different metric to do model selection, or filter out the models where `n_clusters == 1`.